# when i create soap request and call the soap service in android then i get fault string from server where my pdf string length is18139367

Tags: java, android, android-ksoap2, fault

public SoapObject createRequest(PatientBean userBean,
            SamplingBuffers[] memoryBuffer,byte[] pdfByteArray) 
{

SoapObject soapObject = new SoapObject("http://tempuri.org/","TeslService");

```
    soapObject.addProperty("tokenNo", "123456");
    soapObject.addProperty("patientID", userBean.getId());
    soapObject.addProperty("patientFirstName", userBean.getFirstName());
    soapObject.addProperty("patientLastName", userBean.getLastName());


     File file = new File("/mnt/sdcard/htl/demoa.txt");
     StringBuilder text = new StringBuilder();
    try {
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(file));
        String line;
        while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
            text.append(line);
        }
        br.close();
       //text string length=18139367
    }
    soapObject.addProperty("pdf", text.toString());
```

return soapobject;

Comment: What do you mean by Fault string??

Answer (score 0):

Memory limit issue. If I am not wrong thats about 18MB text data in that text variable

Answer (score 0):

You should NOT send a binary blog like a PDF in a soap envelope. Instead send the URL to is in the soap envelope and then do a normal download of the PDF.